Problem with releasing artifact after maven update
After I updated maven from 3.3.9 to 3.9.6 in the project, I cannot perform release to the selected artifact repository. I want to get artifact to the release repo, not snapshot.
I'm using the maven-release-plugin, with the command:
mvn -U -s ${MVN_SETTINGS} release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=${params.RELEASE_VERSION} -DdevelopmentVersion=${nextDevVer} -DtagNameFormat='@{version}' -DscmCommentPrefix='${commitPrefix}'

with some important configurations from pom.xml:
<version.plugin.docker>1.2.2</version.plugin.docker>
<version.plugin.surefire>2.22.2</version.plugin.surefire>

<dockerio.server.id>docker-releases</dockerio.server.id>
<dockerio.registry.url />

<docker.opt.root>/my/dir</docker.opt.root>
<docker.base.java.version>17-slim</docker.base.java.version>

<docker.registry>docker-snapshot.my.repo</docker.registry>

<docker-release.registry.prefix>docker-release.my.repo</docker-release.registry.prefix>
<debian.version>11-slim</debian.version>
<docker.base.java.version>17</docker.base.java.version>
<docker.base.java.image>${docker-release.registry.prefix}/repo/debian/${debian.version}/java-jre:${docker.base.java.version}</docker.base.java.image>

<docker.server.id>docker-releases</docker.server.id>
<docker.registry.prefix>${docker.registry}</docker.registry.prefix>
<docker.registry.url />
<docker.src.dir>src/main/docker</docker.src.dir>
<docker.filtered.dir>${project.build.directory}/docker</docker.filtered.dir>
<docker.image.name>${project.artifactId}</docker.image.name>
<docker.fqdn.image.name>${docker.registry.prefix}/repo/${docker.image.name}:${project.version}
</docker.fqdn.image.name>

and
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.plugin.docker}</version>
    <configuration>
        <registryUrl>${docker.registry.url}</registryUrl>
        <serverId>${docker.server.id}</serverId>
        <dockerDirectory>${docker.filtered.dir}</dockerDirectory>
        <imageName>${docker.image.name}</imageName>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
                <goal>tag</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <image>${docker.image.name}</image>
                <newName>${docker.fqdn.image.name}</newName>
                <resources>
                    <!-- Docker build has no access to files outside build context
                    (which is dockerDirectory cfg entry). Therefore, we are copying result jar
                     to that directory here using docker plugin.
                     That approach does not require separate ADD entry in Dockerfile. -->
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>${docker.opt.root}/deploy</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${uber-jar.name}</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>push</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>push</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.fqdn.image.name}</imageName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

and:
<profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>releaseVersion</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <docker.registry>docker-release.my.repo</docker.registry>
    </properties>
</profile>

Any help would be really great!
I did tried to check if the update to lower version also provide such problem - managed to try maven version 3.6.3 - it's working the same.
I checked the maven logs, with -X parameter.
The only thing that I found weird, was that while I used pre-updated maven, I had that I wanted:
12:58:12  [INFO] [INFO] Built my-project
12:58:12  [INFO] [INFO] 
12:58:12  [INFO] [INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:tag (build) @ my-project ---
12:58:12  [INFO] [DEBUG] Configuring mojo com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:tag from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5cb0d902]
12:58:12  [INFO] [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:tag' with basic configurator -->
12:58:12  [INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) forceTags = false
12:58:12  [INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) image = my-project
12:58:12  [INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) newName = docker-release.my.repo/my-project:0.987.20

(the newName is OK)
but while using updated maven, had something like it:
13:05:24  [INFO] [INFO] --- docker:1.2.2:tag (build) @ my-project ---
13:05:24  [INFO] [DEBUG] Loading mojo com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:tag from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5cb0d902]
13:05:24  [INFO] [DEBUG] Configuring mojo execution 'com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:tag:build' with basic configurator -->
13:05:24  [INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) forceTags = false
13:05:24  [INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) image = my-project
13:05:24  [INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) newName = docker-snapshot.my.repo/my-project:0.987.21

(the newName looks suspicious)

The used version of the docker-maven-plugin is more than four years old.. and there are no updates anymore .. also I see very old versions of plugins like surefire etc... ?

@khmarbaise, yes, I know the package docker-maven-plugin was updated like almost decade ago... And it's archived, no updates are planned.
I think we should move to some other plugin that do the thing but I still wanted to know if there could be some other way.
